# How can I solve Play Store Error ”unknown error code during application install:-102“

Tags: google-play-store

When I update the ES File Explorer today, I met the error. And I have checked a lot of site. Most of the site never mentioned the -102 error code. How can I solve it.

I have checked this [post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2733038) on the xda-developers, but I cannot found the error code -102.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559039/installing-from-android-market-unknown-reason-102) mentioned the error code -102, but the question is I am not the developer. I cannot change the signing certificate.

Comment: Your question title says "error -102", while in the body you write "error 120". Am I correct to assume the title is correct (copy/paste), while the body is full of the same typo? Maybe you could [edit] your question and fix that up? ;)

Comment: Such things happen. Seeing you've accepted my answer, I think it's save to assume the "102" is the right number – so I'll fix up your post accordingly. Btw: [here's another list with playstore errors](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info), just in case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google Search turned up different possible reasons for that. Let's walk them one-by-one:

#### [Installing from Android Market. Unknown reason-102](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9559039/2533433)

This post on our sister site gives the most likely reason in your case, being a problem with the certificate:

> I solved this with using a different signing certificate. The Android docs suggest a life of 10,000 days, but that now creates expiry dates after the end of time in *nix timestamps, which is some time in 2038. I generated a new cert that expires in 2037 and resubmitted the apk and it now installs ok. Unfortunately I had to change the identifier of the app and copy all the descriptions/graphics to the "new" app because play won't let you change the cert on an existing app.

As you cannot fix *this* yourself, it would mean contacting the dev to check and fix.

#### [Android InApp Purchases Error Code 102](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27728970/2533433)

Unlikely to match your case, as *ES File Explorer* is a free app requiring no payment. But for others coming here because of the "error 102" in the title, let me quote from that post on our sister site as well:

> Error Code 102 refers to connection refused.
>
> ```
> Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): Unknown error
> ```
>
> Please go through the following link I hope it may help. Link gives the description of network errors but related to Chrome. As your error is a standard error and might not because of your code but due to some configuration settings.
> https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/117805?hl=en

Comment: -102 error still come out. And I have the problem with MX play Pro.

Comment: Sorry to read, but I'm afraid I cannot give further advice – except for contacting the resp. developers, which I already mentioned in my answer.